# iPhone development on PC: Best Option?

Tags: iphone

I keep reading things about Airplay SDK and Dragonfire SDK.  Are these legitimate options for iphone development without a Mac?  Anyone have any better solutions?

Comment: "Anyone have any better solutions?" Yes, a Mac

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer your question, but a Mac Mini is an affordable way to get started, and it even works with two monitors. I use one.

Answer (score 6):

You're not going to get away from the need of OSX regardless of framework due to signing etc.

Before I bought my epic 2007 MacBook at €300 I used VmWare to run OSX and as such access Xcode. 
No promise on legality of the procedure, but it's pretty much that, Hackintosh or buying a Mac.

In terms of Legal iOS development it's OS X or nothing. Plain and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Life is too short.

A Mac Mini is an affordable option and it will hold it's resale value on eBay well.

Answer (score 0):

DragonFire SDK is an easy way to get started if you own a PC and don't want to get a mac. I had it up and running in a few minutes.  Was learning off the tutorials in a few hours.  Seems if you want a more comfortable/non workaround then you will need to get a Mac.  The price tag for a Mac is what pushed me to DragonFire for now.  A little cheaper option is looking at the refurbished macs.  Save a few hundred and  still get the warranty.